# How to create Cubes in SpagoBI?

Tags: olap-cube, spagobi

I am new to SpagoBI.
I am using `SpagoBI studio` to connect with MYSQL server.
I can able to upload my `Business models` into SpagoBI server.
I want to create a `cube` i.e., fact table using the database tables (`MySQL`) which I have connected in my studio.

Please suggest some fruitful solutions to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are some steps that you have to follow to create cube:-

1. Select file -> New -> Project -> create project under SpagoBI
2. Then , create report under Report Desgin.
3. Create data source , data set connection.
4. Click on Business model -> Create new model -> select connection (as per data source connection all the tables will be shown to you) ->  then finish 
   5.then select table , Right click on table x and -> OLAP -> select Cube -> then finish.
5. x ->  Expand Attribute -> Create measure
6. Write click on y  table -> Create Dimension
7. On the Top , Business Model:-  Right click -> Choose add relationship
8. Rename Business Relationship Name (if you want) -> select table in both side and column that you want to put relationship between them.
9. Right click on store -> click Edit Hierarchy -> then Add hierarchy -> then select as you want to add on hierarchy.